# How to save state of instance class?

Tags: php, oop

There is one class:

```
Class A {
  public function Q(){
      return value;
  }
}
```

In loop I create some exemplars of class A:

```
while ($i < 5){
   $obj_$i = new A();
   $obj_$i->Q();
}
```

Where can I save all results of `$obj_$i->Q();` for each iteration on loop?

Because I after I need to trasfer these objects in another class to handling.

```
Class B {
   public function Result(){
      return $obj_$i + 3;
   }

}
```

Comment: Push it to an array.

Comment: I want to operate only objects

Comment: What do you want to do with this statement, `return $obj_$i + 3;`?

Comment: No, there are a lot function in class `A`, result of them I need to sum in another class

Comment: @Huligan I've given an answer below. Hopefully this will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array and push the objects to this array in each iteration of `while()` loop, like this:

```
$objArray = array();
while ($i < 5){
   $objArray[] = new A();
}
```

Later, pass this array to `Result()` method of class `B` for further processing,

```
class B {
    public function Result($objArray){
        foreach($objArray as $obj){
            // your code
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is more elegant oop method to do that? I mean pattern, possible pattern dependency?

Comment: @Huligan Right now, it's little bit unclear what you're trying to achieve. However, if you want to use/manipulate `$objArray` array extensively inside class `B`, then you should go for *Dependency injection* pattern i.e.  maintain a instance variable to hold this `$objArray`, and while constructing the object of class `B`, pass this array to the constructor method and assign this array to the instance variable. In this way, it'd be easier for you to access this array throughout the scope of an object.